# Minimal list of sub-sets covering elements

Tags: optimization, set, set-cover

Given a list of sets which contain elements:

```
[setA: {a, b, e},
 setB: {d, e, c}.
 setC: {a, d}
]
```

and a list `L` of elements needed to cover: `[x, y, z, ...]`

find the smallest list of sets from L whose union contains all elements in the list `L`.

Is this problem the same as Set-Cover (implying it is NP-Complete)? Or is there something I am missing about this that makes it tractable?

Assume one can determine if an element x exists in a set in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists. The first is the list of sets **L<sub>1</sub>** whereas the second is the list of elements to cover **L<sub>2</sub>**. Discard in polynomial time all the elements that are not in **L<sub>2</sub>** from each set in **L<sub>1</sub>**  and you will get a set cover problem. Therefore, if you have a polynomial time algorithm to solve your problem, you will get a polynomial time answer to the Set Cover problem too.